# Getting an array of checkbox values in the controller

Tags: checkbox, yii, yii2

In the form there is such group of checkboxes

```
$form->field($model, 'ingredients')->checkboxList(
        ArrayHelper::map($ingredients, 'id', 'name')
    )
```

In html it looks like

```
<input name="Dish[ingredients][]" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="Dish[ingredients][]" value="2" type="checkbox">
```

How I can get an array of checkboxes values in the `actionCreate` method of controller?

I trying do it like this

```
Yii::$app->request->post('Dish[ingredients]', [])
```

but I get an empty array.

Addition:

`Ingredients` property is not present in generated model `Dish`, I'm had added it later by the hand. `Dish` and `Ingredients` have a `many to many` relationship. 
How to add `ingredients` to the`Dish` model correctly?

Now if I do

```
$model = new Dish();
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
var_dump($model->ingredients);
```

`$model->ingredients` is empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `ingredients` attribute in the `Dish` model:

```
public class Dish {
  public $ingredients;
  ...
}
```

Load all the post data to your model and then access the `ingredients` array:

```
$model = new Dish();
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
var_dump($model->ingredients);
```

Comment: I clarified the problem in my question

Comment: Just create an attirbute where to load the array, and then work with it

Comment: I had added setter for `ingredients` and it all worked. Getter was already. With public property also works. Thank you